# Sample mean of product of independent variables

Tags: statistics

If two random variables $X$ and $Z$ are independent, then E($XZ$) = E($X$) E($Z$). But does this equation also hold for the sample mean of $X_{i} Z_{i}$ with i from 1 to n? If not, why?

Comment: Your question is ambiguous. Do you mean "Is mean(x1,x2,...)*mean(z1,z2,... ) = mean(x1z1,x2z2,...)?" The answer to that question is "no".

Comment: Do you mean the sample mean $E(\sum_{i=1}^n X_iZ_i)$?

Comment: Might you have meant $\operatorname{E} \left( \,\prod_{i=1}^n X_i\, \right) = \operatorname{E} (X_1 \cdots X_n) = \operatorname{E}(X_1) \cdots \operatorname{E}(X_n) \text{ ?} \qquad$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For two independent random variables, we do have that $E(XZ) = E(X) E(Z)$ but if we have two samples, let's call them sample $x$ and sample $y$, both of size $n$, then we **cannot** say that $\overline{xy} = \bar{x} * \bar{y}$

Check with a simple example $x=\{1,2,3\}$ and $y=\{4,5,6\}$

We can also see why this happens by looking at the formulas for the means. It is safe to say that, in general: $$\frac1n \sum_{i=1} ^ n x_i y_i \ne  \frac1n\sum_{i=1} ^ n x_i * \frac1n \sum_{i=1} ^ n y_i$$

Comment: And if $n$ is extremely large, would this then hold?

Comment: It still in general would not hold. Looking at the equations, we have one side with $1/n$ and the other side has $1/n^2$ when you multiply them together. The left hand side and right hand side would normally still be different.

Comment: The 1/n cancels out the fact that you have n terms. Doubling n doubles all of the sums, and since there are two sum on the RHS, there are two 1/n factors.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are asking if

$E\left[\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_{i}\right)\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}Z_{i}\right)\right]=E\left[\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_{i}\right)\right]E\left[\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}Z_{i}\right)\right]$

The answer follows from using the fact that $\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_{i}\right)\left(\sum_{j=1}^{n}b_{j}\right)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n}a_{i}b_{j}$ on both sides to expand out the expressions. First pull the constants $\frac{1}{n}$ out, then on the left expand out first then take $E$ into the sum, and on the right take $E$ into each sum then expand out. For example the left expression expands out to

$\frac{1}{n^{2}}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n}E\left[X_{i}\right]E\left[Z_{j}\right]$